# COUNT Nulls in GROUP BY in same result (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a little confused about how to count Null values in a query.

I have a basic table which has the number of phone calls for each category. I currently count how many times a call has been received about a category like this:

```
SELECT COUNT (Calls) AS Calls, Category
FROM dbo.Calls
GROUP BY Category
```

This works fine and gives me an output showing the total numbers of calls for each category. However, some categories have had no calls. These are not displayed because COUNT does not count Null values.

With this in mind, how can I get one single output that both counts all the calls to each category *and* show 0 next to each category which doesnt have any calls?

Some examples on the internet show that this is possible when two tables are involved and doing an OUTER JOIN. But if I just have the one table - what can I do here?

Comment: Somehow, you have to have a list of the categories that should be included in the results regardless of whether they are in the `dbo.Calls` table.  If you do not already have a table with the categories, you would have to provide them some other way, such as a temp table, common table expression, etc.  Otherwise, there is no way for the query to determine what these "missing" categories are.

Comment: @Livewire, do you have NULL values for categories that doesn't have calls

Comment: @Livewire, you need to have a seperate table of categories. see this code. it works fine. create table mytable
(
  calls int,
  categoryid int
 );
 
 insert into mytable values (1,1);
 insert into mytable values (NULL,2);
 
 select COUNT(Calls) as calls, categoryID
 from mytable
 group by categoryID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Counts for categories which aren't represented in dbo.Calls

To accomplish this, you'll need a list of the categories which must always appear in the results... and then you'll need to perform a [`left join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) between those categories and your calls.

Do you have a categories table? If so:

```
select
 cat.Category
,count(c.Category)
from dbo.Categories as cat
    left join dbo.Calls as c
    on c.Category = cat.Category
group by cat.Category
```

<sub>Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/808f3/3)</sub>

If not, you could explicitly list the category values (assuming they're strings):

```
select
 cat.Category 
,count(c.Category) as Calls
from (values
   ('Bat-Phone')      
  ,('Domestic')
  ,('International')
) cat(Category)
  left join dbo.Calls as c
  on c.Category = cat.Category 
group by cat.Category
```

<sub>Here's another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e457eb/4)</sub>

### Counts for uncategorized calls

If you simply want to see uncategorized calls as well, use [`coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [`isnull()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to provide a dummy category for nulls, like so:

```
select
 isnull(c.Category, 'Uncategorized') as Category
,count(*)
from Calls as c
group by isnull(c.Category, 'Uncategorized')
```

<sub>And another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8963/1)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this do it, or am I missing something?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Calls IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Calls, Category
FROM dbo.Calls
GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: The OP seems to suggest that there are some categories which don't exist in `cbo.Calls` but he'd like them returned with a `0` count anyway. So, he couldn't get that information by simply querying `dbo.Calls`.

Comment: "Seems to suggest"?   Can we get that confirmed?   The impression I get is that all the categories are in the Calls table, but some have NULLs in the Call column.  The subject and first line of the post suggest that he only needs to know how to count the NULLs as 0s.

Comment: If that were the case, he'd already get `0` from `count()` ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42356)).